# How to edit bitnami virtual machine files

Tags: php, linux, virtual-machine, lamp, bitnami

I downloaded a virtual machine image for Bitnami lamp.

I got an OVA file from https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/virtual-machine
Which I imported into virtual box on my local machine running Ubuntu.

What I can't figure out is how do I start writing code?

The bitnami virtual machine only has vim and I can use it to write code through the terminal.

But since I have no experience using vim, I want to use VsCode which is installed on my host machine.

I want to access the virtual machine files using VsCode on my host machine.

I tried connecting to the server using ssh but that still doesn't let me use VsCode.

I also tried mounting the VDI disk image to my host machine but I couldn't write any files as the disk was mounted in read-only mode.

I really just want to edit files on the virtual machine.

But I can't find any docs on how to use any text editor other than terminal based ones.

How do you usually code on bitnami virtual machines?

Comment: _"How do you usually code on bitnami virtual machines?"_ You don't. Instead you just run them and you deploy your code (application) on them. Just edit with VSCode as you do, commit to git, run the build on the revision and then automatically deploy when its green. Then do the integration testing. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, I'm to write code locally and then upload the files to the server?

Comment: Yes, and because you do that often, you automate that upload. The virtual machine is not for editing the code but to host the application and run it.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Can you please point me to a documentation/ tutorial on how to automate the upload?

Comment: No idea about tutorials, but you're perhaps looking for some pointers on tooling. If so, I'd recommend `rsync` for starters. It's robust and boring and works with SSH that is commonly used for such transactions. It's not truly deployment, but does the uploads. Then there is also `git` itself with the `git archive` command that creates zip- or tar-balls from (git) revisions. There is also `make` as a build manager. All these tools are well documented. Look forward to have a "one button deployment", like a single click or terminal command to build a revision and push it out.

Comment: And reading you're using virtual box locally: There is a tool called `vagrant`, that could fit here very well, too: It mounts your project directory into the virtual "box", that is you get a true development environment and don't need to upload revisions as this is your working directory. So you can edit files locally in your editor and it will be also available in the virtual machine. It is a dedicated setup (so development environment and not production) but on the other hand makes development more production near as you're using the same machine image. You can combine both approaches.